# How to XOR two strings using Python?

Tags: python, xor

If I have:

```
cipher_text1 =  "3b101c091d53320c000910"
cipher_text2 = "071d154502010a04000419"
```

How do I XOR the two cipher texts using Python to get:

```
cipher_text1_XOR_cipher_text2 = "3c0d094c1f523808000d09"
```

Thanks

Comment: Are `cipher_text1` and `cipher_text2` the plain text or binary?

Comment: It may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408173/byte-operations-xor-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the `int()` function, which allows you to specify a base in which to interpret a string to be converted to a numeric value.  The default base the function assumes is 10, but 16 works too and is what's appropriate for the strings you have.  So you convert your two strings to numeric values with `int()`, and then perform the XOR on those values.  Then, you apply the `hex()` function to the result convert it to a hex string. Finally, since you asked for a result without `Ox` at the front, you apply the appropriate slice to chop off the first two characters of what `hex()` returns:

```
cipher_text1 = "3b101c091d53320c000910"
cipher_text2 = "071d154502010a04000419"

cipher_text1_XOR_cipher_text2 = hex(int(cipher_text1, 16) ^ int(cipher_text2, 16))[2:]

print(cipher_text1_XOR_cipher_text2)
```

Result:

```
3c0d094c1f523808000d09
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
cipher_text1 = "3b101c091d53320c000910"
cipher_text2 = "071d154502010a04000419"

def xor_ciphers(cipher1, cipher2):
    bin1 = int(format(int(cipher1, 16), f'0{str(len(cipher1))}b'), 2)
    bin2 = int(format(int(cipher2, 16), f'0{str(len(cipher2))}b'), 2)
    return hex(bin1 ^ bin2)


print(xor_ciphers(cipher_text1, cipher_text2))
```

Output:

```
0x3c0d094c1f523808000d09
```